# Problemas NodeJS e MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Olá estou tendo problemas com excesso de conexão com `node-mysql2` utilizando um pool de conexão. Gostaria de saber se existe uma melhor prática quanto implementação, e qual o melhor driver a se utilizar com `nodejs` e `mysql`?

Obs: Minha aplicação tem um `longpolling` e muitos usuários.

Comment: Michael, a resposta acertou na tua dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

O módulo mais usado creio ser o [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Eu uso-o assim:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'nomedaBD',
    debug: false,
    charset: 'utf8_unicode_ci'
});

function query (query, data, callback) {
    if (typeof data == 'function') {
        callback = data;
        data = [];
    }
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) return onError(connection, err, callback);
        connection.query(query, data || [], function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return onError(connection, err, callback);
            connection.release();
            callback.call(this, null, rows, fields);
        });
    });
}
```

O `plugin` mantem a ligação à BD aberta e tem uma *pool* para gerir ligações como no exemplo em cima.